# Dynamically adding Signature Tags to a Docusign Template through API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using a template for signature requests using the code from the Docusign reference [Java walkthrough](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate).

Is it possible to dynamically add signature tags on the template through the API? I modified the java code given in the walkthrough (***my modifications demarcated below***) but it does not seem to add a signature tag on the template:

```
    "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
       "<templateRoles>" +
            "<templateRole>" +
               "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
               "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
               "<roleName>" + roleName + "</roleName>" +
               ====== My code modifications ======
               "<tabs>" +
                  "<signHereTabs>" +
                     "<xPosition>100</xPosition>" +
                     "<yPosition>200</yPosition>" +
                     "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                     "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                  "</signHereTabs>" +
               "</tabs>" +
              =====================================
           "</templateRole>" +
     "</templateRoles>" +
    "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

I was expecting a signature tag at the specified position on the template but it is not working. Is the xml I added incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can have multiple signature tabs you need to further specify by wrapping an extra `signHere` xml tag around each.  Right now you have:

```
"<signHereTabs>" +
    "<xPosition>100</xPosition>" +
    "<yPosition>200</yPosition>" +
    "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
    "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
"</signHereTabs>"
```

Try using this instead:

```
"<signHereTabs>" +
    "<signHere>" +
        "<xPosition>100</xPosition>" +
        "<yPosition>200</yPosition>" +
        "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
        "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
    "</signHere>" +
"</signHereTabs>"
```

Notice the extra set of `<signHere></signHere>` xml tags that wrap the actual tag.

Comment: Thanks, Ergin. That solved it. Appreciate your help.